# Apache Ignite async sql query

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ignite

In Apache Ignite like this sample in its documentation: [Link](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/SQL/custom-sql-func)

```
SqlFieldsQuery query = new SqlFieldsQuery("SELECT name FROM myCache WHERE sqr(size) > 100");
cache.query(query).getAll();
```

I want to run this query **async**, but I can't find GetAllAsync() method.
Does it just run **sync**?

Comment: The documentation and sample code you linked to is for Java, not .NET

Comment: The documentation for Ignite’s `async` API for .NET is here: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/net-specific/net-async

Comment: It's not for SQL APIs

Answer (score 0):

SQL API in Ignite is sync only. There are no async overloads.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's very bad. Is there a solution?

Comment: @MasiumDev while I understand that sync-only API can be limiting, can you please provide more details on your use case - what exactly is an obstacle?

Comment: for example, when I call a large query (15 seconds), the application's thread waits for the response.